# How to print two different sheets with different scale options using Excel 2007 and Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, printing, xlsx

I have two sheets in a .xlsx file.

The first sheet uses columns A to C and fits into a **single landscape orientation A4 size paper**.

The second sheet will fit into a **single landscape orientation A4 size paper width with infinite pages tall**. It uses columns A to L.

But when I select both sheets to print or when I select Print Entire Workbook, the preview always shows the second sheet to have some of the columns "chopped off".

If I print each sheet separately, it is fine. Of course the words on the printed first sheet look bigger than the words on the printed second sheet. I believe the second sheet is scaled down to about 47% in order to fit into the width of a landscape A4. The first one retains the 100% scale.

Another option is I choose to print both sheets at a scale of 47%. But of course, that means the first sheet does not maximize the width of the printed page and the words will look unnecessarily small on the first printed sheet.

My question is:

**is there a way to print both sheets in a single print command while retaining the different scales for both sheets using Excel 2007 and 2010?**

If the method involves preparing the Excel xlsx file in some way, I would like to know as well.

Currently, I am using PHPExcel to generate this xlsx file for an enterprise client hence the request.

The client is not tech savvy and I want to find out just how possible this can be achieved.

Answers need not involve knowledge of PHPExcel. I will simply take your Excel related answers and figure out how to accomplish it using PHPExcel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the orientation and print settings in each sheet separately. Manually, you'd use the options on the Page Layout ribbon for that.

Sheet1 can be portrait with print area set from A1 to G30, for example. Sheet2 can be landscape with print area set from A1 to Q26, for example and scaled to print on one page.

Select each sheet individually and see the correct print preview.

Select both Sheet1 and Sheet2, or use "Print Entire Workbook" and the print preview will show Sheet1 in portrait and Sheet2 in landscape.

Here are some screenshots of the print preview, page 1 and page 2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried selecting Sheet 1 as 100% and Sheet 2 as fit to page width. It did not work when I print entire workbook. I am using excel 2010.

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me. Can you post a file with dummy data that shows the problem? I added screenshots of what I see on my system.

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s32/sh/35d29817-ef3f-4c6f-8b59-4cb6ec407c7d/a9f738e766465f6f0686ebdf4c7ca3bd

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you intend to do and what does not work? I see three sheets, all set up for landscape. The Summary sheet prints at 100% and the next two sheets print at custom resolution set to 1 page wide by 100 [sic!] tall.

Comment: I wanted to know if it is possible to use Print Entire Workbook and have the summary sheet print as landscape at 100% but the other pages print at landscape but 1 page width and 100 page tall

Comment: Yes, that's how your workbook prints for me. Does it not do that for you?

Comment: teylyn: it does not show that in print preview. I am using mac microsoft office. What are you using?

Comment: You never mentioned Mac until just now. If you are a Mac user, you may be aware that some things work differently on a Mac than on a Windows machine. I think it is instrumental to cite your operating system when you use a niche product instead of the common standard. Sorry, I cannot help with the Mac aspect. The problem does not exist in Excel for Windows. Maybe you want to ask the question in a Mac forum instead.

Comment: apologies for not mentioning Mac earlier. It did not strike me when  I was troubleshooting the problem earlier. I will mark your answer as correct first and go test the .xlsx file on a windows office. Thank you~~!